# Trying to run rails server and getting stuck with some error regarding "Adapter"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

does any know what the solution to the below is pls? Thank you

I run `rails server`

```
ubuntu:~/environment/oursurplus (master) $ rails server
```

I get the following reaction / response:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.7.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        59: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        58: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        57: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        56: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        55: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        54: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        53: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        52: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        51: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        50: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        49: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        48: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        47: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        46: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        45: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        44: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        43: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        42: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
        41: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:102:in `start'
        40: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:148:in `log_to_stdout'
        39: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
        38: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `app'
        37: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
        36: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        35: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
        34: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
        33: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
        32: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
        31: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        30: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
        29: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        28: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        27: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        26: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        25: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        24: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        23: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        22: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        21: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        20: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        19: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        18: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        17: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        16: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        15: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        14: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:121:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        13: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:40:in `on_load'
        12: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:40:in `each'
        11: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:41:in `block in on_load'
        10: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
         9: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
         8: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
         7: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
         6: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
         5: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
         4: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
         3: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
         2: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
         1: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/_adapter (LoadError)
        59: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        58: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        57: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        56: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        55: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        54: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        53: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        52: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        51: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        50: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        49: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        48: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        47: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        46: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        45: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        44: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        43: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        42: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
        41: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:102:in `start'
        40: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:148:in `log_to_stdout'
        39: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
        38: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `app'
        37: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
        36: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        35: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
        34: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
        33: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
        32: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
        31: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        30: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
        29: from /home/ubuntu/environment/oursurplus/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        28: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        27: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        26: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        25: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        24: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        23: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        22: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        21: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        20: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        19: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        18: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        17: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        16: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        15: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        14: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:121:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        13: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:40:in `on_load'
        12: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:40:in `each'
        11: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:41:in `block in on_load'
        10: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
         9: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
         8: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
         7: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
         6: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
         5: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
         4: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
         3: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
         2: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
         1: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/_adapter'. 
Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. 
If you use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
```

Here is my database.yml file which i think is alright.

```
default: &default
  adapter: <%= ENV['DATABASE_ADAPTER'] %>
  encoding: <%= ENV['DATABASE_ENCODING'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV['DATABASE_POOL'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>

development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  <<: *default
  database: oursurplus_development
 
# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: oursurplus_test
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
 
production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

When i try to run `rails db:migrate` i get the following same error

```
ubuntu:~/environment/oursurplus (master) $ rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
LoadError: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/_adapter'. 
Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. 
If you use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.
```

Comment: What is the value of your environment variable ENV['DATABASE_ADAPTER'] and are you sure it is both accessible and return a valid value ? Also you mention your adapter twice : in default and respectively in each environment. It may not collide in Rails but it would be more readable to mention only once.

Comment: Share your gem file. Make sure the gem 'sqlite3' is present.

Comment: yes 'sqlite3' is present in gemfile